# a flat json to a grouped/merge json

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

For example:

from

```
[{
        "SchoolYear": 2017,
        "Type": "cat 1",
        "Count": 7236,
        "total": 43864,
        "Percentage": 16.50
    },
    {
        "SchoolYear": 2017,
        "Type": "cat 2",
        "Count": 36628,
        "total": 43864,
        "Percentage": 83.50
    }
]
```

to

```
[{
        "SchoolYear": 2017,
        "cat 1 count": 7236,
        "cat 2 count": 36628,
        "total": 43864,
        "cat 1 Percentage": 16.50,
        "cat 2 Percentage": 83.50
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScripts `Array.reduce()` is very good at doing things like this.  For example:

```
const startValues = {
  "SchoolYear": 0,
  "cat 1 count": 0,
  "cat 2 count": 0,
  "total": 0,
  "cat 1 Percentage": 0,
  "cat 2 Percentage": 0
};

const output = input.reduce((result, reportObj) => {
  const newCount = result["total"] + reportObj.Count;
  const cat1Count = reportObj.type === "cat 1" ? reportObj.Count : 0;
  const cat2Count = reportObj.type === "cat 2" ? reportObj.Count : 0;
  const cat1Total = result["cat 1 count"] + cat1Count;
  const cat2Total = result["cat 2 count"] + cat2Count;

  // Not sure what you would want to do if the school year is different?
  result["SchoolYear"] = reportObj.SchoolYear;
  result["cat 1 count"] += cat1Count;
  result["cat 2 count"] += cat2Count;
  result["total"] += newCount;
  result["cat 1 Percentage"] = cat1Total / result["total"];
  result["cat 2 Percentage"] = cat2Total / result["total"];

  return result;
}, startValues);
```

Comment: Is the reduce method convert from group json to flat json? It may have school year 2016, 2015 and so on. The same format as school year 2017 in the flat json.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood your question: I thought you wanted to produce a summary object from an array of records.

Comment: Don't add snippets that are broken when ran. Use a code block instead when showing an example.

Comment: Thanks: I wasn't aware that snippets and a code blocks were two  different things.  For others that are interested, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367517/how-to-use-code-snippet-vs-code-block